# Fill missing values in a data frame based without losing values already in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame with missing values:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Brand':['residential','unclassified','tertiary','residential','unclassified','primary','residential'],
    'Price': [22000,25000,27000,"NA","NA",10000,"NA"]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

print (df)
```

Resulting in this data frame:

```
             Brand  Price
    0   residential  22000
    1  unclassified  25000
    2      tertiary  27000
    3   residential     NA
    4  unclassified     NA
    5       primary  10000
    6   residential     NA
```

I would like to fill in the missing values for residential and unclassified in the prices column with fixed values (residential =1000, unclassified=2000), however I dont want to lose any values that are already present in the prices column for residential or unclassified, so the out put should look like this:

```
        Brand  Price
    0   residential  22000
    1  unclassified  25000
    2      tertiary  27000
    3   residential   1000
    4  unclassified   2000
    5       primary  10000
    6   residential   1000
```

Whats the easiest way to get this done

Comment: Try your browser searches again.  "impute data" is the missing phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do `map` with `fillna` , PS:  you need to make sure in your df, NA is NaN

```
df.Price.fillna(df.Brand.map({'residential':1000,'unclassified':2000}),inplace=True)
df
          Brand    Price
0   residential  22000.0
1  unclassified  25000.0
2      tertiary  27000.0
3   residential   1000.0
4  unclassified   2000.0
5       primary  10000.0
6   residential   1000.0
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the price shows up as a float, is it because of map? can we keep it as an int? Also thanks for the answer

Comment: @John since you have NaN before ,and NaN type is float in panda